# hide next column upon getting total in previous column

Tags: excel, vba

I have been assigned work on Excel & Macro, and I am not much aware of those. 
Task is to Hide Next Column automatically(withouht being refreshed or press F2) if Previous Column Total is 0. and incase if its Total is >=0 then unhide itautomatically(withouht being refreshed or press F2).

Assume I have Set of Columns & Rows(say C11 to C20) where I have to enter values (say 0 or >=0), and once i reach last cell(say C20) which has Formula of Sum for particular column(C11 to C20), If total is 0 then next column (say D) should get Hide without pressing any key if total is >=0 then column D should be as it is.

Please help me out.

Here is the code to Hide Column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$C$31" Then
If Target <= 0 Then
Range("D31").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
Range("D31").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
End If

If Target.Address = "$D$31" Then
If Target <= 0 Then
Range("E31").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
Range("E31").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
End If

If Target.Address = "$E$31" Then
If Target <= 0 Then
Range("F31").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
Range("F31").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use the worksheet_Change event and instead of having multiple ifs, use only one if + Offset to hide the next column.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for replying. Hiding Column is working fine. But i need to auto Refresh the sheet upon column entry or say as auto change event.

Comment: What do u mean by autorefresh? What should refresh? Formulas? Pivots? Charts? What exactly do you want to refresh?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Formulas..

Comment: In that case why don't you keep the workbook's autocalc mode to Automatic? No code is required...

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sir sorry for troubling you. I would like to change the question, will update it again. Please have a look at it once and do the needful.

Comment: Sure.. just leave a message here after you update. Don't forget to add the `@` sign

Comment: @SiddharthRout Please go through the post Sir. I have updated my Question. Hope I am Clear this time about the Question what I am asking :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sir i hav updated d post and left a message.

Comment: Your post says that the last cell C20 has the formula but the code is checking in C31. Could you please confirm which cell has the formula? Also it would be nice to see a sample sheet.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry for that. Formula is in C31 and i cracked d solution will update it can u check it let me know plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution i found after googling for this long. I am using this only for 1 column right now.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rCell As Range

For Each rCell In Range("C11:C31")
If Range("C31").Value = "0" Then
    Range("D31").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
If Range("C31").Value <> "0" Then
    Range("D31").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
End If
Next rCell

End Sub
```